# Using Vs2012 on a team that uses 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

If I am the only person on my team that uses vs2012, can I assume that as long as I target version 4 of the framework that other colleagues that are using 2010 will have no issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work fine. Just make sure that your colleagues have SP1 (VS2010) installed.

Comment: I don't see SP1 listed when I display Help=>About in VS2010. Is there anything about SP1 that would require a corresponding update in production in order to ensure that binaries compiled on a machine with SP1 installed work in production? I assume not, that the SP impacts only VS, not the binaries produced by VS, provided that the source code has not changed. Just being very cautious...

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

I'm building sharepoint apps, and constantly switching from vs 2010 and VS 2012 with no issue, even on the same computer.

Microsoft had the good idea to maintain the project and solution compatible in the two ways.

You should be careful thought, that the projects kind are compatible.

Comment: Yes, I use both VS 2010 and VS 2012 too.  So far no problems switching between versions on any project.